# elasticsearch search_phase_execution_exception error

Tags: elasticsearch

I don't understand the error I get when scrolling through the elasticsearch API. I sometimes get an error when running an airflow dag and sometimes I don't? which makes me so confused and would like to understand the error.

This is the error I get:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.NotFoundError: NotFoundError(404, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'No search context found for id [605457312]')
```

```
data = es.search(index = "xyz/xyz", body = match, scroll = '1m', request_timeout=30)
```

where `match` is just filtering over a range and the `size` is set to 50.

Any comments would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying iterating over the data in elasticsearch with the data retrieved by `es.search` method, I suppose the scroll timeframe is not enough to iterate over all the results.

`scroll = '1m'` means Elasticsearch will discard the search session after 1 min you executed the first search. So I can first suggest increasing the scroll to a larger value.

Comment: If this didn't help you to solve the issue, please provide more information about
- the number of data
- the number of rows you are trying to process
- the number of workers working concurrently

Comment: Hi, well in the documentation of this api service says, it should be kept as 1m or we can be blocked... Number of shards is 6 and the total is around 2 million. But the thing is I'm always deleting a scroll and starting a new scroll after each year if that makes sense

Comment: Could you please add more information how does your query looks like, and which document you refer to? thanks!